# Let's get critical: Jul 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Windows Phone Stack Exchange](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Backup of saved Wi-Fi networks](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/backup-of-saved-wi-fi-networks)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Can you ruin a battery by letting it fully drain?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/can-you-ruin-a-battery-by-letting-it-fully-drain)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Group text messaging with iPhone users](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1936/group-text-messaging-with-iphone-users)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What is the technical text below reviews in the Windows Phone Dev Center?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/what-is-the-technical-text-below-reviews-in-the-windows-phone-dev-center)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Finding/Setting the first day of the week](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1893/finding-setting-the-first-day-of-the-week)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How can I hard reset my Windows 8 phone (which keys do I press?)](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/how-can-i-hard-reset-my-windows-8-phone-which-keys-do-i-press)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [App to access Google drive?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/app-to-access-google-drive)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Syncing music changes file names, album art, and artist, how do I change this?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1968/syncing-music-changes-file-names-album-art-and-artist-how-do-i-change-this)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Emails from gmail show up twice on phone email app](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/emails-from-gmail-show-up-twice-on-phone-email-app)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why does my lockscreen not update the bing image of the day?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1890/why-does-my-lockscreen-not-update-the-bing-image-of-the-day)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)